# MVC 5 facebook/google authentication, without email

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I implemented Facebook/Google authentication according to this article:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on, but after authentication users are prompted to input their email address. Is there any way to authenticate the user without asking for their email? I'm pretty sure many sites do that. Any guidance or article appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In AccountController in the function ExternalLoginCallback  replaced the line

```
return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
```

with all the lines inside the function ExternalLoginConfirmation